# How to capitalize first letter of each word if it starts with "a" or "o"?

Tags: c++

I have the following c++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
void main()
{
    
     ifstream file;

     file.open("file.txt", fstream::out);

     string text;


    while (!file.eof()) {

         getline(file, text);
 
     }

    file.close();





    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

         if (text[i] == ' ' && text[i + 1] == 'a' || "o") {

             text[i + 1] = toupper(text[i + 1]);
         }
     }
```

Text of the file:

```
Cats odds abses intro obsession jam
```

And I need co capitalize the first letter of words that begin with "a" or "o",but it capitalizes each letter.

Does somebody know how to fix this?

Will be thankful for any answer.

Comment: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/12149471)

Comment: Try `if (text[i] == ' ' && (text[i + 1] == 'a' || text[i + 1] == 'o'))`...

Comment: I recommend you read word by word (using `>>`) into a string. Then it's very easy to check each word by itself and modify it.

Comment: @Paul Sanders. Thanks Bro, it's helped

Comment: @ Some programmer dude. Thanks, will be trying it

Comment: On a side note, why are you using the `out` flag with an `ifstream`? You are not doing output with the stream, so get rid of `out`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this condition:

```
text[i + 1] == 'a' || "o"
```

There are *two* errors here.

1. The first is that you use a *string* for `"o"` not a single character. Use `'o'` instead.
2. The second problem is that the condition is actually the same as

   ```
   (text[i + 1] == 'a') || "o"
   ```

   Which means you compare only `text[i + 1]` to the character `'a'`. So the condition is true if either `text[i + 1] == 'a'` is true, or if `"o"` is true. And `"o"` will *always* be true, making the whole condition true, always.

The two problems are unrelated. Even if you solve the first one, the second will still remain, as `'o'` is *also* always true.

To solve the second problem you need to compare `text[i + 1]` with both characters explicitly:

```
text[i + 1] == 'a' || text[i + 1] == 'o'
```

Comment: And that should be in parentheses, because of the precedence of the logical operators.